# Why is ordering values necessary for nonparametric regression

Tags: nonparametric

Suppose we are want to consider the asset price $P_t$ (business daily) of some stock. The log return is defined as

$$X_t:=\log{\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}}$$

suppose we are considering the prices between some interval, eg. June 1986 and March 1990). Log returns can be modelled by $X_t=\sigma_t\epsilon_t$, with $E[\epsilon_t]=0,Var(\epsilon_t)=1$. We assume Markov-property, thus $\sigma^2_t=v(X_{t-1})$. The model can be fitted by nonparametric regression of the function $v$ in

$$Z_t:=X^2_t=v(X_{t-1})+\phi_t$$
where $\phi_t=\sigma^2_t(\epsilon^2_t-1)$ can be seen as error. We want to use `ksmooth`, `smooth.spline` and `loess`. In my notes they say: "First we sort the values, in order not to get problems with `ksmooth`, which orders the values internally and gives back results corresponding to the ordered values."

I do not understand why we have to do that. Basically we have a function $v$, with values on the $y$-axis and the $x$-axis is our time interval between June 1986 and March 1990. So why do we have to order the data?

Answer (score 1):

It is an **implementation** detail. `ksmooth` is documented to return the points at which the smooth was evaluated in *increasing* order of `x`, the input data.

```
Value:

     A list with components

       x: values at which the smoothed fit is evaluated. Guaranteed to
          be in increasing order.

       y: fitted values corresponding to ‘x’.
```

Note also that what `ksmooth()` returns is a vector of `n.points` points, evenly spread across the range of `x` (unless argument `x.points` is supplied during fitting), **not** the evaluation of the smoother at the input location `x`.

Read `?ksmooth` for more details.

Comment: Thank you Gavin Simpson for your comment. Two questions: if I do not use the argument `x.points`, how exactly are the points chosen? If I add `x.points` then the returned `y` values correspond to the `x.points`. After all, why is it necessary to order my input `x`. In my notes there are other examples about `ksmooth` where we do not order `x`. Should it be done generally using `ksmooth`? Again, thanks for your help